# SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... = ... returns empty array after fetchAll()

Tags: php, arrays, apache, pdo

I am trying to `fetchAll()` an array for rows in my database that are from a certain category.

```
<?php 
require 'database.php'; 
$class = $_GET["class"];
$classes = $conn -> prepare("SELECT * FROM items WHERE class = $class");
$classes -> execute();
$all_items_from_class = $classes -> fetchAll();
?>
```

On the previous page I want the user to click on a category and lead him to a page where it loads all items of that specific category, the URL will show something like website.com/category.php?class=bla and display all items from that specific class. After trying different `foreach` loops and not getting any results, I checked with a `var_dump()` to see what is wrong with the array `$all_times_from_class` and to my surprise it returns a completely empty array.

When I remove the WHERE from SELECT it returns the entire array of all items, but for some reason it does not with WHERE. I used `$_GET` in the same way in another .php file and it works fine there, but not when I try to `$_GET` the class. Why does it not return an array for that specific category? Does it not recognise what class to get from the URL, does it not work for VARCHARs in the database? I'm at a loss at the moment. The only fix I know would be to `foreach()` the entire database and run every row through an `if`.

Comment: First, you could grab the errors because we could see something helpful through that, add at the top of the file these lines `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`  and run the code with the query implemented as you like. If there is an error it will really help you - if no errors are shown that means the problem is not in your syntax.

Comment: put quotes around `$class`

Comment: you are using prepare/execute wrong way. check the linked question

Comment: @RST you better delete your comment

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos There were no errors showing up sadly

Comment: Check the comment above which says about having your prepare statement wrong. Normally it should display errors if the statement is syntax-wrong

Comment: @YourCommonSense This worked, thank you very much.